# Asp.Net Core MVC Movie App - Scaffolding Item not working properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am following the tutorial for Creating a Asp.net Core MVC App.

[Asp.Net Core MVC Movie App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

I am at the point where i am needing to scaffold the movie model.
I am right-clicking on Controllers --> then am going to Add --> New Scaffolded Item...

I click on it and it displays something completely different then what is expected.  Here is what it is displaying:

[image]

How do i get the display to show what is showing in the tutorial?  What am i not understanding?  Thanks.

Comment: As you can see from [this image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model/_static/add_scaffold21.png?view=aspnetcore-2.2), you should be able to choose different sorts of scaffolding in the left-side menu, among others from categories "Common", "Identity" (this is the category, that it seems like you jump directly into) and "Layout", which makes it seems like you are missing some dependencies or similar.

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/290#issuecomment-158465907) by "prafullbhosale", you need to register entity framework and dependencies to access scaffolding. Take a look at his comment. Did you include those namespaces in your project?

Comment: Finally, here is a link if you need to get started with [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/). Please note that the first opening lines (lines 3 and 4) from your tutorial/the tutorial you linked writes: "You use these classes with Entity Framework Core (EF Core) to work with a database. EF Core is an object-relational mapping (ORM) framework that simplifies the data access code that you have to write." I don't know why they don't show you how to include Entity Framework, but this might be what you are missing

Comment: If that's not enough, go into your Visual Studio Installer and make sure you have installed "Entity Framework 6 tools" etc. with you ASP.NET Development workload and try over again, while following the MSDN page I linked together with your tutorial, because you missing Entity Framework seems to be the problem here. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the above suggestions, I still wasn't able to get the proper items to display for me.  I then finally decided to uninstall Visual Studio 2017 and do a fresh install.  I created my project, added the Entity Framework dependency, and now the proper items are displaying.